# What are the limits for the waivers to sanctions against Russia within the European Union?

Tags: european-union, sanctions

According to [this article](https://nltimes.nl/2022/10/24/netherlands-issued-91-waivers-sanctions-russia), the Dutch government has issued 91 waivers from sanctions against Russia since the country invaded Ukraine late in February:

> In April, the European Union banned ships sailing under the Russian
> flag from European ports. The Ministry of Infrastructure and Water
> Management issued waivers so 34 ships could access Dutch ports, for
> example, because they carried important cargo like aluminum and food.
>
> The Ministry of Finance granted 13 additional waivers related to
> frozen assets or goods that fall under the sanctions regime.
>
> The Ministry for Climate and Energy, which falls under the Economic
> Affairs, issued 25 waivers for Dutch organizations to still get energy
> from former Gazprom companies. The waivers help 150 companies and
> organizations, including municipalities, schools, and water boards,
> the Ministry said to the broadcaster.

I tried to find more information about the limits of an EU state government issuing such waivers and I could find [food mentioned as a particular exception](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/policies/sanctions/restrictive-measures-against-russia-over-ukraine/sanctions-against-russia-explained/):

> The sanctions do not block the export of and transactions related to
> food and agricultural products.

It is not clear if EU sanctions also include some details about how much an EU government can use waivers to circumvent these sanctions or if it is a gray area.

Comment: A case that was reported in German [press](https://taz.de/Uran-aus-Russland/!5881722/) in September was a delivery of enriched uranium originating from [Rosatom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosatom) to a [plant](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brennelementfertigungsanlage_Lingen) in Lingen/Germany. The nuclear fuel rods produced there are powering the French nuclear power stations. The uranium was shipped [from St. Petersburg](https://taz.de/!5876705/) to the port of Dunkerque by a Russian ship.

Comment: @ccprog That's interesting information. I wonder if EU countries have some informal freedom, something like "exceptions are allowed, as long as they are not too big / not too frequent."